# Adding row inside row of a loop in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a feeling this is either very simple or I am doing it wrong. I have a bootstrap table and want to add row inside a row when the button is clicked. Currently it is adding the row to the table. I have not worked with tables and learning.

```
           <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Products</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
```

Working plunker to my problem. http://plnkr.co/edit/FMICwZC22KwzcYBGESAz?p=preview  according to answer by @Coldstar

What I have Tried.

1) Nested Table did not worked.
2) Rearranging my `<tr>`

Please help where you can.

Expected Result:

Want to add the Row after the product list

```
->Row of Product 1
 -->Row of the Delivery inside Row of Product 1
->Row of Product 2
 -->Row of the Delivery inside Row of Product 2
```

Comment: because you are using table layouts that is virtually impossible

Comment: @Bradgnar not impossible if use `ng-repeat-start` along with `ng-repeat-end`

Comment: so you want to rebuild the table each time?

Comment: what is the expected results layout?

Comment: I still feel like @GeekOnGadgets would be better off using the grid system

Comment: It's hard to tell to be honest because once I look at the plunker I can't tell if they actually want to add a row or if they want to add data inside of a column.  Right now the table is not right because there is a <th> tag inside one of the <tr>'s where there should be a <td>

Comment: @Bradgnar that was a typo sorry. I want to have a delivery for that particular products. If you look at plunker the rows are getting added after my product list.

Comment: @charlietfl I tried using mg-repeat-start and end. I am getting closer but still behaving odd. Can you please have a look at the plunker and help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="product in deliveryData">
        <td>{{product.productName}}</td>
        <td><a href ng-click="addItem($index)" class="btn btn-primary">Add delivery address</a></td>
        <td>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr ng-repeat="delivery in product.deliveries">
                    <td>{{delivery.description}}</td>
                    <td>{{delivery.quantity}}</td>
                    <td><a href ng-click="removeDelivery($parent.$index, $index)" class="btn btn-primary">Remove</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the controller: ($scope.delivery should actually come from a static form for future reference so you can avoid the copy() function)

```
    $scope.delivery = {
        description: 'Hello World',
        quantity: 2
    };

    $scope.deliveryData = [
        {
            productName: 'Product A', quantity: '20', deliveries: []
        },
        {
            productName: 'Product B', quantity: '10', deliveries: []
        }
    ];


    $scope.addItem = function ($index) {
        var d = angular.copy($scope.delivery);
        $scope.deliveryData[$index].deliveries.push(d);
    };

    $scope.removeDelivery = function (par, chi) {
        $scope.deliveryData[par].deliveries.splice(chi, 1);
    };
```

Comment: I tried your solution. Its behaving same as what I have got.The problem now is when I click on button to add delivery for product A it add both to Product A and B. Can you please look at plunker?.

Comment: ok fixed example. worked fine locally for me. with proper nesting, you should avoid using **ng-repeat-start** and **ng-repeat-end**

Comment: Thanks :). But now the removeItem does not work. I am getting the index of the addItem and passing it to removeItem, but only works first one. Any Idea where I am being N00b?

Comment: Can you post code or update plunkr. All you really have to do is to pass the 'delivery' item to a function like **remove(delivery)** and pop it from its parent list. or make use of the $parent.$index

Comment: That's the first thing I tried did not worked. Update my Plunker :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the power of bootstrap use:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The divs from bootstrap are much easier to style, also you can dynamically add anything inside of a row.  This is what bootstrap refers to as its grid system and can be seen here:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid